# Creating a list in python with strings and using the for function

Tags: python, string, list, integer

I've just come back to using python and need some help with creating a list, I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
For x in range(0,1001):
         print("string"x)
```

But I've forgotten how to do it. I'm basically trying to make a list with the same word but ascending numbers next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe :

```
new_list = [f'string{i+1}' for i in range(1001)]
```

**Output** :

```
['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5', 'string6', 'string7', 'string8', 'string9', 'string10', 'string11', ...]
```